# Has Deligne-Rapoport been translated?

Tags: reference-request, modular-forms

The classic text of Deligne and Rapoport giving a model for the mod p reduction of the modular curve is found in a "Lecture Notes in Mathematics" volume.

Has it been translated from the original french and/or LaTeX-ed so that it can be searched more easily?

Answer (score 2):

I would be extremely surprised if there existed a translation or a LaTeX version. I have a searchable pdf of it though. Annoying Megaupload link: http://www.megaupload.com/?d=F6GBYUBU

Answer (score 1):

There is no translation in my knowledge. But there is a later book by Katz and Mazur on "Arithmetic Moduli of Elliptic Curves", which is in English and which ought to a good amount of the things in the paper of Deligne and Rapoport.

Comment: The main difference between DR and KM is that the former carefully treats the cusps from a moduli point of view, whereas this is absent from KM.  On the other hand, KM uses Drinfeld level structures to obtain moduli theoretic interpretations of certain constructions which appear in a more *ad hoc* way in DR (e.g. the moduli-theoretic interpretation of $X_0(p)$ in char. p).